# Baby Rudin Exercise 4.13 Alternate Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, cauchy-sequences

I would like to know if my proof of ex 4.13 is correct.  Thanks!

Exercise 4.13 in Rudin asks: Let $E$ be a dense subset of a metric space $X$, and let $f$ be a uniformly continuous real function defined on $E$. Prove that $f$ has a continuous extension from $E$ to $X$.

My proof:

Suppose $p \in X \setminus E$.  Then there is a sequence $\{p_n\} \to p$ in $E$, because $p$ must be a limit point of $E$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $E$, we have for each $\epsilon > 0$ the existence of a $\delta > 0$ such that $$d(p_n, p_m) < \delta \implies d(f(p_n), f(p_m))<\epsilon$$  However, since $\{p_n\}$ converges, it is also Cauchy so that there is some $N$ such that $$n, m \geq N \implies d(p_n, p_m) < \delta \implies d(f(p_n), f(p_m))<\epsilon$$ This statement implies that $\{f(p_n)\}$ is Cauchy.  Now since $f$ is real-valued, cauchy sequences converge and thus $\{f(p_n)\}$ converges.  Now just define $$g(p) = f(p) \text{ if } p \in E$$
$$g(p) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n) \text{ for } p \notin E, \{p_n\} \to p \text{ in } E$$

This is the desired continuous extension.($p_n$ is an arbitrary sequence in $E$ that tends to $p$)

Comment: Your work is correct

Comment: I think you are missing 2 things: (1) That $g(p)$ is well-defined: That it is independent of which sequence $(p_n)_n$ in $E,$ converging to $p,$   is chosen . (2), That $g$ is continuous on $X$...... You had a trivial typo (E/X for X/E) which was my edit,

Comment: FYI, the only fact required about the codomain $\mathbb R$ is that $\mathbb R$ is complete, so the same proof works if the codomain of $f$ is any complete metric space. For bonus points (after fixing the two issues identified by user254665), you may also want to prove that the continuous extension is unique, and is in fact uniformly continuous. :-)

Comment: Also as a pedantic note, you are using $d$ to indicate the metric on both the domain and the codomain, and in general these won't be the same function. I know this is a common abuse of notation, but it's still an abuse.